# Always open Bootstrap popover when click on it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap popover opening on first time click, closing on second time click. Here I want to open popover when click on it either it is first time or second time.

Please suggest me.

```
<i class="fa fa-file" id="popoverDwnFiles"></i>

$("#popoverDwnFiles").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $('#divDownloadContent').html();
    },
    title: '<span class="text-info">Exported Files</span>' +
   '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;#popoverDwnFiles&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>',
    placement: 'bottom'   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, popover closed when again click on popover trigger element but it's default behaviour can be over-ride by `trigger: 'manual'`

```js
$("#popoverDwnFiles").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $('#divDownloadContent').html();
    },
    title: '<span class="text-info">Exported Files</span>' +
        '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;#popoverDwnFiles&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>',
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'manual',
}).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).click(function (e) {
    $(this).popover('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<i class="fa fa-file btn" id="popoverDwnFiles">Open Me</i>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zonf3k12/)

Answer (score 3):

Set `trigger` to `manual` and manually `show` it on click event.

```
$("#popoverDwnFiles").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $('#divDownloadContent').html();
    },
    title: '<span class="text-info">Exported Files</span>' +
    '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;#popoverDwnFiles&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>',
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'manual'
}).on('click', function (event) {
    $("#popoverDwnFiles").popover('show');
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/2154/**